# Synchronous Lambda & SNS integration

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, aws-step-functions

I have to handle a synchronous request to API Gateway -> Lambda (Node.js). The request contains a transactionId. The lambda needs to forward the request payload to a Step Function, & await the output of the Step Function to return to the client. I'm thinking that this may be possible with a synchronous Lambda invocation if it can:

- make an async call to post the request payload to the step function
- [subscribe to an SNS topic event source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/sns-examples-subscribing-unubscribing-topics.html), with a filter policy applied so that it only consumes messages with the same transactionId as that received in the request body from the API Gateway
- process the message as it's received from the SNS topic, and return it to API Gateway

...but I'm not understanding whether an existing Lambda invocation can subscribe to an SNS topic & await a message, or if SNS performs the invocation...in which case, this wouldn't work? Any assistance would be appreciated!